# Imputing a numeric age variable from interval/grouped/bracketed age ranges

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, data-imputation

I am using data from the National Survey on Drug Use and Health, which reports age in a combination of years and brackets of various sizes: 20, 21, 22-23, 24-25, 26-29, etc.

[image: age brackets]

Rather than use these categories, I am interested in operationalizing age as a numeric predictor in a regression. Is there an established method for deriving age as a numeric variable from intervals? I know similar things have been done with income brackets (Bhat, 1994) but I haven't seen anything similar for age.

Bhat, C. R. (1994). Imputing a continuous income variable from grouped and missing income observations. Economics Letters, 46(4), 311-319.

Comment: (1) A predictor derived from these categories won't be continuous but might be numeric; a simple example is calling 26 to 29 year-olds 27.5 years old, & so on. Is that the kind of thing you mean? Or imputation of age from other information you have on individuals together with their age category? (2) It would help to outline Bhat's approach & explain any difficulties that arise in applying it to age rather than income.

Comment: Thank you! That's right - numeric, not continuous. The midpoint approach makes sense but was wondering if there was a "best practice" here. I'll add to the post shortly

Comment: Regarding Bhat's approach, I'm afraid it's too complicated for me to summarize here (and I don't entirely understand it) - I also think it's too complicated for my use case. I'm interested in a relatively straightforward approach - like the midpoint approach you suggest - with something I can cite to support it

Comment: Another option would be to stick with categories and treat them as ordinal in the regression. This blog post gives some support for this https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats3/OrdinalIndependent.pdf

Comment: Perhaps then, (3) you could state your goals. If you're purely interested in being able to make predictions of the response for individuals given their age category & other predictors, a wider range of approaches are open to you than if you already know the functional form of the relation of the response to age & need to estimate an unknown parameter or parameters.

Comment: I did a lot of this kind of thing 20 years ago and found it worked well to interpolate based on Census data by age for relevant geographies.  Even when your sample doesn't follow the age distribution in its parent population, there's still a good chance that interpolating within the age bins in a way that follows the shape of the parent distribution will be reasonably accurate.  This presupposes nothing is operating to create sharp deviations in age distribution: for instance, that your sample doesn't preferentially include adults whose ages are even numbers, say.

Comment: Furthermore, tying the scores to a reference distribution (external or internal, & regardless of exactly how) facilitates making predictions for data where the banding of age is different from the data to which your model was fitted.